# split and map pyspark dataframe fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use pyspark to do some manipulations to data but I'm having an issue which I can't seem to solve. Basically, I have 2 columns which contain a string of date

```
field1 (string): date1 date2 date3 date4 date5
field2 (string): 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
```

every value is related to each other (so date1 is related to the first value in field2, date2 is related to the second value in field2, etc.

What I want to achieve is convert the dataframe into rows like:

```
field1  field2
date1   0.0
date2   1.0
date3   2.0
date4   3.0
date5   4.0
```

i've tried:

```
df.split(field1, ' ')
df.explode(field1)

df.split(field2, ' ')
df.explode(field2)
```

but this will create a multiplication:

```
field1  field2
date1   0.0
date1   1.0
date1   2.0
date1   3.0
date1   4.0
date2   0.0
date2   1.0
date2   2.0
date2   3.0
date2   4.0
etc..
```

So I thought that I should split the string and then do map

```
df.split(field1, ' ')
df.split(field2, ' ')
df.create_map(field1,field2).alias(mapped_val)
df.explode(mapped_val)
```

However, this doesn't work because i get an error on `create_map`:

```
 TypeError: Unhasable type: list
```

I'm not sure how I could get this to work, How would i convert the split() output towards something that works with create_map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip the arrays and explode, select it back to the dataframe again.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('date1 date2 date3 date4 date5', '0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0')]).toDF('col1', 'col2')

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('array', arrays_zip(split('col1', ' '), split('col2', ' '))) \
  .withColumn('array', explode('array')) \
  .select('array.*').toDF('col1', 'col2').show()

+-----+----+
| col1|col2|
+-----+----+
|date1| 0.0|
|date2| 1.0|
|date3| 2.0|
|date4| 3.0|
|date5| 4.0|
+-----+----+
```